# Override the require function

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Is it possible to override the *global* `require` function, affecting it at `process` level?

From what I know, the `require` function is provided as argument in the function that wraps the NodeJS scripts:

```
(function (..., require, __dirname) { // something like this
   // The wrapped code
})(...);
```

Is there any way to modify the `require` function?

```
(function () {
    var _require = require;
    require = function () {
        console.log("...");
        _require.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

This will probably affect only the script where it's located.

How can we modify it at the process level?

Comment: It appears the 6to5 does something along these lines for its [require hook](http://6to5.org/docs/usage/require/).

Comment: You could try overriding `global.require` in your main file. `global.require = function(){}`.

Comment: I'd be interested to know *why*?

Comment: @mscdex I expected this question. :-) I will show you later.

Comment: @BenFortune I need to override it from another file, modifying it in all scripts. I tried with `global.require = ...`, but it didn't get modified.

Comment: @ssube Does it modify a function this way?

Comment: No, require in node is module specific this is not possible.

Comment: The only module with access to the real require is the REPL

Comment: https://github.com/alexlawrence/cjs2web can replace `require` in your `node.js` application with it's custom implementation. It actually bundles many `node.js` scripts into one. What do you mean by the _process level_? Is compiling custom `node.js` executable an option? Once you explain clearly the **why** and **what** then the **how**-options will be more visible

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
var Module = require('module');
var originalRequire = Module.prototype.require;

Module.prototype.require = function(){
  //do your thing here
  return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for this snippet.

Comment: Just noticed your answer. Sorry for marking this answer so late! Thanks!

Comment: May I know where I need to place this code to make sure this is called for every require call (typescript)?

Comment: This is an interesting solution but don't you find it a bit nasty. I'm trying to justify myself using it :)

Answer (score 11):

[mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) does this by [overriding `Module._load`](https://github.com/boblauer/mock-require/blob/21dedf1eb3ccbc3ce2d6c01e38dd888d8df61d89/index.js#L9-L15) (which is what the [real `require` actually calls](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.2.0/lib/module.js#L354)).

Comment: I have abstracted this in a simple module that provides a conditional interface to override module resolution logic (and enables to reset the original module resolution logic) https://github.com/gajus/override-require

Answer (score 11):

Here is a much safer native ES6 answer based on @orourkedd which acts like an event listener on all require calls, It might look like its replacing require but if you look closer its actually saying: `require = require` and trap calls to it but return original behaviour. This is just one of the millions of uses of `Proxy()` which has been really handy for me, for example in Typescript for mapping tsconfig "paths" with the real module node will resolve.

I would go as far as to say that this is not "Monkey patching" as its on a lower level of the language.

```
var Module = require('module');
Module.prototype.require = new Proxy(Module.prototype.require,{
    apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList){

        let name = argumentsList[0];

        /*do stuff to ANY module here*/

        if(/MyModule/g.test(name)){
            /*do stuff to MY module*/
            name = "resolveAnotherName"
        }

        return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList)
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh I forgot you can release proxies too so this is not permanent.

Comment: The fact that you're using Proxy doesn't affect the fact that it's monkey patching (not that monkey patching here is necessarily bad).

Comment: In your answer you said you used it make tsconfig's paths work. Can you please share your code for that? I've been struggling with tsconfig's paths from last 1 week. It would really help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the workaround I found. If there is any better solution, I'm open to see it.

I created a script named `req-modifier.js`:

```
module.exports = function (_args) {

    var _require = _args[1];
    function newRequire () {
        console.log("Require is called");
        return _require.apply(this, arguments);
    }          
    newRequire.__proto__ = _require;

    _args[1] = newRequire;
};
```

Then from the files I want to modify the `require` function, I do:

```
require("./req-modifier")(arguments);

var foo = require("./foo");
```

The limitation is that I have to call every time the `req-modifier` function.

Comment: "The limitation is that I have to call every time the req-modifier function." - that practically means you have to call your own thing from every module you'd like to be able to do this. Not really a solution at all.