# Is it possible to launch js files with different permissions using nodejs/npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to launch a js file in a js file with different permission. Just like this:

`main.js` (which gets started)

```js
config = JSON.parse(require("./config.json")) // <- should be possible

console.log(config.authkey) // <- should be possible

require("./randomJSFile.js").run()
```

`randomJSFile.js` (which will be executed by main.js)

```js
exports.run = () => {

 let config = JSON.parse(require("./config.json") // <--- this should not be possible, only the main.js file should have access to the config.json file

 console.log(config.authkey) // should not be possible

}
```

Does anyone know how to do something like that?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to prevent access to the file like that, when you can simply just refrain from accessing the file anywhere else in your code?

Comment: I did not code the `randomJSFile.js` file. I just want to get files from other devs, add it to my code, without need to review every file.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't know of a way to do exactly what you're asking but you could encrypt your config and then create a helper function in your main file that decrypts it and accesses properties. That way even if they do try to access the config, they won't get anything readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a snippet from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948300/override-the-require-function) you could possibly override the require function to check for the filename, something like this:

```
const Module = require('module');
const originalRequire = Module.prototype.require;

Module.prototype.require = function() {
  if (!arguments.length || typeof arguments[0] !== 'string') return {};
  if (arguments[0].includes('config.json')) return {};
  return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

And then perform this override after you've already required the config in your main file, so you don't accidentally block yourself

Comment: Smart! Thank you!

Comment: @Xge no problem